# how to know where to publish if user account has more than one profile

Tags: jquery, facebook

this may be simple, but I guess it isn't, and really Facebook docs are not really useful since they aren't translate to my mother language, making hard to achieve my goal.

ok, I have a script to enable my webapp to post to my feed on Facebook, but I've a personal feed, a app page and a test page.

How do I tell my script, based on login that I want to post on my test page and not on my personal profile?

this is the code I'm using to login

```
var appID = 'MY_APP_ID';
        var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
        var queryParams = ['client_id=' + appID, 'redirect_uri=' + dominio, 'response_type=token'];
        var query = queryParams.join('&');
        var url = path + query;
        window.open(url);
        //
        FB.init({appId: appID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        //
        var accessToken = "";
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                accessToken = response.session.access_token;
                console.log(accessToken);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
            login();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
            document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                accessToken = response.session.access_token;
                console.log(response.session);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
            login();
        });
        function login() {
            FB.api('/me/accounts?access_token='+accessToken+'', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.name) {
                    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = "Ligado ao Facebook como "+response.name;
                }
            });
            $('body').criar_paineis_edicao(accessToken);
        }
```

and this one to actually publish

```
if(accessToken) {
    console.log("com token");
    FB.api('/me/feed?access_token='+accessToken+'', 'post', parametros, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            $.each(response.error, function(name, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            alert('Conteudo também publicado no Facebook');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

```
console.log(response);
```

produces this

Object

```
data:array[2]
    0: Object
        access_token: "my token"
        category: "Computers/Internet"
        id: "my first id"
        name: "my name"
        __proto__: Object

1: Object
        access_token: "my token_2"
        category: "Application"
        id: "my second id"
        name: "my name"
        __proto__: Object
        lenght: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post to `/{<id}/feed` where **{id}** is the page or user id where you want to post - /me will always refer to the user whose access token you're using

Comment: ok, thanks, so with my login I get an object within 3 Arrays, one for each feed, personal, app and page, how can I parse it to build a new array just with {personal_id, app_id, page_id}, allowing me to then choose where I want to publish? Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure i understand; you'll have the user ID of the user from the Facebook API, you can pull a list of their pages if you have the manage_pages permission by making a call to `/me/accounts` and then you cn post to whichever target you want

Comment: I edited the question, adding the console.log.    now I try to push each id into an array, but I get error  var fb_ids = [];
response.data.each(function() {
    fb_ids += $(this).id;
});

Comment: got it! Thanks for help, using this I can now have a selector and choose where I want to post in Facebook.

Comment: var fb_ids = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
//console.log(response.data[i].name);
fb_ids[i] = response.data[i].name +"|"+ response.data[i].id;
}